# October CMS + RainLab.Pages + Indikator.News = Undefined index: slug

Tags: php, octobercms

When I add menu link to post-list:

**main-menu.yaml**:

```
title: news
type: post-list
code: ''
cmsPage: news-list
replace: '0'
viewBag:
    isHidden: '0'
    cssClass: ''
    isExternal: '0'
```

I'm handling error:

> Undefined index: slug
>   /home/vagrant/Code/foo/plugins/indikator/news/models/Posts.php line 256

```
$page = CmsPage::loadCached($theme, $pageCode);
if (!$page) {
    return;
}

$properties = $page->getComponentProperties('newsPost');
if (!preg_match('/^\{\{([^\}]+)\}\}$/', $properties['slug'], $matches)) {
    return;
}

$paramName = substr(trim($matches[1]), 1);
    return CmsPage::url($page->getBaseFileName(), [$paramName => $item->slug]);
}
```